# is it possible to access someone's file on local pc via git&github?

Tags: git, github

so the picture is like this:
(A's html in their local pc)-(A's html on github)-(B's html on github)-(B's html in their local pc)

A is supposed to be able to access B's html on github and modify the content.
is it also possible for A to access B's github to modify the content on B's html in their local pc?
or it is only possible on github?

Comment: Are you looking for security vulnerabilities or trying to set up a remote Git server?

Comment: hmm I think it can be about security vulnerabilities(even though I wasn't approaching from security wise). but without doing any other extra settings, is it possible to edit someone's file in the other's local pc?

Comment: You'd need to set up a public facing server that implements one the [supported protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) and make the appropriate arrangements in the involved firewalls. I don't think that can happen by mistake with any git distribution from a reputable source.

Answer (score 1):

Git is not automated synchronisation.

Git allows you to push (upload) commits (a bunch of changed files) and also allows to pull/fetch (download) those later.

When you push something to GitHub (or another git server), other people with access can pull and push to this repository and therefore changing the files on GitHub..

When the person then pulls from the repository, those changes will be downloaded and applied.

However, this process is not automated (except you create a script that does this or similar).

As I already said, it is possible to configure access.

GitHub has two visibility types: `public` and `private` (actually, there is also `internal` or similar for GitHub Enterprise, I think).

`public` repositories are visible to everyone but can only be edited by collabrators.

`private` repositories are only accessible (read/write) for collabrators.

By default, the repository owner (and maybe people in the organitation) is the only collabrator. He/she can explicitely add collabrators if he/she wants to.

It should be noted that, in an organisation, it is possible to configure even more than that.